# How to avoid client-side re-render for static content server-side rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

My question is about server-side rendering and the React client-side check process it performs in the HTML markup when using SSR.

If server produced HTML does not match with client-side virtual representation for the same content, React ditches the HTML received from the server a re-renders the client-side version.

In my case, I have some parts of the main content page that gets rendered dynamically in the server based on some internal data that I know for sure won't change client-side.

Right now, I must pass the internal data in the initial payload so React can create a virtual representation in the reconciliation process so it check is ok and it does not re-render the content.

I would like to avoid sending data to the browser that it doesn't need.

Is there any way I can set a component (tree) to be static so reconciliation process just ignores it and avoid re-render the content?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could check [renderToStaticMarkup()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup)

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I need some parts of a whole page-view to be static. With renderToStaticMarkup is an all-or-nothing way.